# MSBuild Failed to register output

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I'm trying to build a C# project but getting following error:

> *Please try enabling Per-user Redirection or register the component from a command prompt with elevated permissions.*

As much I remember, earlier also I faced this issue and at that time I installed a patch provided given at MSDN site. But it's not working now.

I'm using Windows 7 & VS 2008.

Comment: which patch, and what kind of output are you referring to in your question's title?

Comment: Although I forgot the link of that patch, but here is the file name - "VS90SP1-KB976656-x86"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute it from a command prompt window that has been "Run as Administrator"!

Comment: I think this is not happening after I migrated to VS2010